# Left and right justifying using formatter in java- can't figure out how to format properly

Tags: java

I'm working on outputting elements of arrays and left/right justifying them appropriately, however I'm having difficulty getting the output to align properly. This is my output as of right now-

```
Houston      TX   2009834
Detroit      MI    925051
Indianapolis   IN    783612
Washington   DC    570898
Burlington   VT    180000
```

as you can see, the third line is off by a couple spaces. is there a way to specifically access this line of output and format it properly? My line to print is this-

```
for(int i = 0; i < pop.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("%-10s%5s%10d\n", city[i], state[i], pop[i]);
    }
```

Comment: *the third line is off by a couple spaces* -- Hint: How many letters are in "Indianapolis"?

Comment: ahhhh i see now. the documentation on formatting was a bit confusing for me. now i understand how it functions. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing number of characters indicated in your `printf` in

```
"%-10s%5s%10d\n"
```

This pads city names to 10 characters. Change it to

```
"%-15s%5s%10d\n"
```

To be able to handle city names up to 15 characters (or whatever length you want).